# xml value checking for state based uitableviewcells

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nsxmlparser

I have a main view in which I am trying to restrict some of the tableview cells from being selected so that the user enter their details in a particular order I want to define.

The first cell lists a bunch of manufacturers, the user selects a manufacturer which will then pop the subview from the view controller stack and then pass the value of the manufacturer + id back to the main view.

At the moment, that then allows the second cell to be selectable.. even if there are no values related to the previously selected manufacturer...

I would like to know the best way possible to do a preliminary check or something along those lines that doesn't slow up the application so that if there is no data the cell stays grey.

Here is a diagram of what I mean:

any help would be greatly appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I created something similar once by dynamically adding the rows to be edited as each of the preceding rows was correctly filled in.  Thus the user only sees those rows that they can manipulate at any given time.   If the other rows are not editable, they are probably not containing relevant data (or even correct data?).

Had to include logic to handle the case where they've entered rows 1, 2, 3 and then go back and change 1 (so you have to remove 3, and then make 2 the one they are editing next, for example).

You can use the animated adding/removing of rows in a UITableView to make the visual appeal good.

Comment: Yep sounds exactly what I have done so far.. The thing I am wanting to do now is dynamically allow or disallow the second cell from being edited depending on the first cells selection depending if it has any related models in the model xml or not.. But because I am doing all of my parsing in the subview I wondering if there is a quick way to check model xml for a related value to the first selected item as you pop the view or if I will have to set up a whole other parser delegate in the main view for doing some of the logic on those tables?